# Converting img src tags to image_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using this script to parse HTML  tags in order to convert them into <%= image_tag... %>

My regex and test cases are here: http://rubular.com/r/sBPAaWSdGQ

I would like to capture src="captureme.jpg" and all the other attributes as well so that I can port them over.

I've got the regex started it's just not quite there yet -- I need something to capture all the attributes... i.e. class, id
Below is what I have so far.

```
class ToImageTag

  def self.convert
    Dir.glob("app/views/**/*").each do |filename|
      next unless filename =~ /\.html\.erb$/
      file = File.new(filename, "rw")

      file.each_line do |line|
        source = /(<\s*img\s*.*src=(.*?)(>|\/>))/.match(line)
        source = src[1].split.first

        image_tag = "<%= image_tag(\"#{source}\")"

        line.gsub!(src[0], image_tag)
      end

      file.close
    end

  rescue => err
    puts "Exception: #{err}"
  end

end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Cannot use nokogiri to parse .html.erb files. Just tried that.

Comment: Use http://hpricot.com/ that's what the HAML folks use to convert ERB to HAML.

Comment: "@Maletor "Cannot use nokogiri to parse .html.erb files.", that's because ERB files are not HTML. They are HTML like, but that isn't good enough to a parser. You could probably do what you want using a SAX processor, that acts like a filter, immediately outputting all the non-img tags and then substitute the template when you have the `src` parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Nokogiri to replace <img src /> tags with <%= image_tag %> ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362189/use-nokogiri-to-replace-img-src-tags-with-image-tag)

Comment: @Maletor, you asked a very similar question previously. Please don't do that. Your previous was using Nokogiri, but I don't think it's enough difference to justify a new question. I'd recommend editing your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using javascript? If so, you can use jQuery to do what you want.

```
var src = new Array();

$('img').each(function(index, element) {
    src[index] = $(element).attr('src');
});
```

I haven't tried this out, so it might not be bug free.

If you aren't using javascript, there are plenty of DOM parsers out there that will simplify this task for you. I don't think using regex is the best option.