# Nokogiri spoils Erb markup

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, erb

I'm using Nokogiri to do some page processing in my Sinatra, Ruby app.

So when I do this:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
s='<a href="<%=@prevHref%>">a</a>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(s)
puts doc.to_s
```

I get

```html
<a href="%5C&lt;%=@prevHref%%5C&gt;">a</a>
```

Code was escaped. How do I avoid this? Actually what I'm doing is:

1. Open template on the disk
2. Parse it with Nokogiri
3. Replace some of the nodes (not the one which gets escaped; some other ones)
4. Save template back to disk
5. Parse template with ERB which obviously fails as ERB markup was spoiled.

Comment: Nokogiri is not made to deal with erb, it is for parsing html and xml. As such it sees invalid HTML and tries to fix it. Escaping the values inside the string attribute as it goes.

Comment: Agreed, you cannot use Nokogiri for this, as Nokogiri does not understand the syntax.  You will need to find some other way to edit the template.

Comment: @maerics has a nice workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362189/use-nokogiri-to-replace-img-src-tags-with-image-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described elsewhere on this page, Nokogiri (and more accurately libxml2) cannot represent Erb internally.  For example, consider this valid Erb template that produces value HTML output:

```html
<p<%="> Hello"%> World!<%="</p"%>>
```

If you think about it you will realize that it's unreasonable to expect Nokogiri to be able to create a DOM out of that.

Instead of using Erb (which cannot be parsed as HTML or XML) you will need to use a templating language that uses valid markup. For example:

- [Amrita](http://amrita.sourceforge.jp/) - takes valid X/HTML and combines with Ruby data structures to produce HTML output.
- [Kwartz](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/kwartz/) - takes valid X/HTML and combines with CSS-like data binding file to produce Erb templates.

Comment: Thanks :) I did not think of nokogiri as DOM constructor, rather as text searcher. I did not expect it to change anything out of the box. Now I understand that Nokogiri starts by ripping my HTML into pieces and making DOM. And only then it can use it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the `s` String through erb first before you can parse it with Nokogiri. Otherwise you're doing it correctly.

Comment: I'm editing ERB template with nokogiri. I do not output it to the user. I'm editing template and saving template.

Comment: @Yan As this answer and the two other comments to your question state, you cannot do this. ERB is not valid XML markup (nor HTML), and so cannot be parsed or represented by Nokogiri/libxml2. You've asked a good question and you have a reasonable desire, but it's not possible.