# Replacing HTML Images with Nokogiri Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

What I want to do do is go through some HTML and replace only the image `src` urls with a base64 encoded image.

So far the code below is replacing whole image blocks, which loses the inline styling.

```
    @doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html_content)
    @doc.at("img").replace("<img> src='BASE64_EXAMPLE_STRING'>")
```

Interested in how I can amend the above code to only replace the `scr` element of an image?

Comment: this looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362189/use-nokogiri-to-replace-img-src-tags-with-image-tag

Comment: I don't want to replace html images with a Rails image ERB tag. Rather I want to edit only the image source URL

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can treat the images I pull from my HTML similar to a hash.

[Documentation](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html)

```
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html_content)
images = @doc.search("img")
images[0]['src'] = "http://example.com"
```

I didn't realise this but it actually edits `@doc` where `@doc` is the original HTML that I inputted. So when I do a `puts @doc` in the command line I can see the first image source has changed to `http://example.com`.

So I should hopefully be able to loop through them all now and change the image source URLs to a base64 encoded image :)